# ListView selected highlighting

Tags: android, listview, highlighting

First, I know there are a lot of questions about the same theme, but I try a lot of solutions and I don't achieve it works.

I have an app with a `DrawerLayout` and I want to change the item selected by code, the option change but the item is not highlight and I don't know why. It muss work in versions >= 2.3 (api 9)
If I click manually it works

The layout of the items are: I put `android:focusableInTouchMode` to false because I read that the selected item don't work if it is enabled.
I put too a background.

The choiceMode: `drawerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector_holo_light"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconoMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etTitulo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/menu_item"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The xml file to the background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo_light"/>

</selector>
```

Then I emule the click on the item with this code (home is the selected option):

```
drawerList.performItemClick(drawerList, home, drawerList.getItemIdAtPosition(home));

drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        changeOption(position, true);

        view.setSelected(true);

    }
});


private void changeOption(int position, Boolean cerrar) {
    fragment = new Home();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    tituloSeccion = ((MenuLateralItem) opcionesMenu[position])
    .getTitulo();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tituloSeccion);

    if ((cerrar) && (!isDrawerLocked)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    }
}
```

Thank you! And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround for this would be to save the value of the selected item in the adapter if the DrawerLayout. Then when you are making the convertView, check if the current item is the selected one and set its custom backgrround accordingly

```
public class YourDrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int selectedItem;
    // all your code goes here


    //call this method in the onItemClick listener of the listview

    public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
        selectedItem = position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //the code for the generating the view..

        //check here if the current item is the selected one
        if(position == selectedItem) {
            //set the selected layout for listItem
        } else {
            //set the normal layout for listItem
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it but the app only call method getView the first time. It's an arrayAdapter. Thank you for your answer

Comment: call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after selecting the item . It will repopulate the listview.

Comment: I had not been able to test yet. I solve the problem. Thank you very much!